Who is the Pischei Teshuva the MB is referring to
In אורח חיים
סימן קל״ה in משנה ברורה ד he quotes a Pischei Teshuvah. Who is he referring to and where do I find it?

במנחה ובשני וחמישי - ואם טעו וקראו להשלשה קרואים בפרשה ראשונה של סדר שבוע העבר או של שבוע הבא לאחר שבוע זה אם הוא מעכב בדיעבד או לא עיין בפתחי תשובה שהביא דעות האחרונים בזה:


See here (R' Yisrael Issur Isserlin) :
https://hebrewbooks.org/7983

